# How to iterate over a list and enter those values in a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, netmiko

```
list1 = [a,b,c]
list2 =[d,e,f]
list3 = [g,h,j]
new_list = []

for i in list1:
    new_dev ={'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':i}
    new_list.append(new_dev)
```

I want to perform the same action as above and iterate over `list2` and `list3` and there values should reflect in `key1` from `list1` and `key2` from `list2`. Thus after appending into the empty list `'new_list'`, it will have three dictionaries as elements. Please help me resolving this.

Think of the elements of the list as the values in the dictionary and so for `key1` the values should be from `list1` and for `key2` the values should be from `list2` and so on. Thus we should be getting a list with three dictionaries as elements in the `"new_list"`.

Comment: You can solve this with a one-liner using 2 `zips` - `[dict(zip(keys,i)) for i in zip(list1, list2, list3)]`, you just need to define `keys` as `['key1','key2','key3']`. More details in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip()` to merge the lists, and then take three elements from the merged list at each iteration step like so:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']
list3 = ['g', 'h', 'j']
new_list = []

for (i, j, k) in zip(list1, list2, list3):
    new_dev ={'key1': i, 'key2': j, 'key3': k}
    new_list.append(new_dev)

print(new_list)

>>> [{'key1': 'a', 'key2': 'd', 'key3': 'g'}, {'key1': 'b', 'key2': 'e', 'key3': 'h'}, {'key1': 'c', 'key2': 'f', 'key3': 'j'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a one-liner using two `zip`s in a list comprehension -

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = ['d','e','f']
list3 = ['g','h','j']

keys = ['key1','key2','key3']                                #<----
out = [dict(zip(keys,i)) for i in zip(list1, list2, list3)]  #<----

print(out)
```

```
[{'key1': 'a', 'key2': 'd', 'key3': 'g'},
 {'key1': 'b', 'key2': 'e', 'key3': 'h'},
 {'key1': 'c', 'key2': 'f', 'key3': 'j'}]
```

## EXPLANATION

1. First you `zip(list1, list2, list3)` the 3 lists together which combines the first, second, third and nth elements of each list together into respective tuples.
2. Next, you iterate through these tuples using `[i for i in (list1, list2, list3)`
3. After that you zip this tuple, with the list of keys using `zip(keys,i)`, which gives you something like `(key1, a), (key2, d), (key3, g)` for each tuple.
4. Finally you convert this zip object to a `dict` using `dict(zip(keys,i)` which converts the first elements of each tuple as key and second elements of each tuple as value.